# make div follow another div's location

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
$('#notepad').hide();
$('#news').hide();
$('#todo').hide();

$('#notepadIcon').click(function(){
    $('#notepad').toggle();
});
$('#newsIcon').click(function(){
    $('#news').toggle();
});
$('#todoListIcon').click(function(){
    $('#todo').toggle();
});

$('button').click(function(){
    $('#todoListIcon').hide();
});
```

```css
#todoListIcon,
#newsIcon,
#notepadIcon {
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 100px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color:#000;
}

#bottomRightIcons {
    bottom:15px;
    right:30px;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
}

#todo,
#news,
#notepad {
    width: 290px;
    height:250px;
    max-height: 350px;
    background-color:#000;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 45px;
    right: 28px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#news {
    right: 152px;
}

#notepad {
    right: 277px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hide todo</button>

<div id="bottomRightIcons">
        <div id="notepadIcon"><i title="Note Taker" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></div>
        <div id="newsIcon"><i title="News" class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i></div>
        <div id="todoListIcon"><i title="Todo List" class="fa fa-th-list"><span id="notificationTodo" class="todoListNotification"></span></i></div>
    </div>

<div id="notepad"></div>
<div id="news"></div>
<div id="todo"></div>
```

Firstly, I decided to make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yj25p1m1/) to help show my issue.

As you can see when you open one of the menus they appear in the correct position, but once you hide one of the icons they don't follow the location of the icon.

Ideally, I'd like the menu div to act as a dropdown menu, as it follows the icon.

Any ideas? Appreciate it.

Comment: It is better to use `code snippet` feature of stack overflow instead of providing link to external fiddle.

Comment: @niyasc apologies, added.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why don't you just $('button').click(function(){
    $('#todoListIcon').hide();   $('#todo').hide();
});

Comment: You have fixed the `right` value of the menus so when the location changes the `right` value remains the same eg. `#news {  right: 152px; }`. You need to reset it according to the new position.

Comment: @anpsmn Right, thats the problem, I'm not sure how to change the `right` according to the new position...

Comment: I dont think you can fix this using CSS. What I would suggest is to expand your jquery and extract the position of the icon and position the black box according to that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue right now is you are having a fixed `right` value for the menus so it remains the same when you toggle their positions. You need to reset the position of the menus on toggle.

I have added classes `icon` and `menu` to the respective divs.

```
<div id="bottomRightIcons">
  <div id="notepadIcon" class="icon"><i title="Note Taker" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></div>
  <div id="newsIcon" class="icon"><i title="News" class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i></div>
  <div id="todoListIcon" class="icon"><i title="Todo List" class="fa fa-th-list"><span id="notificationTodo" class="todoListNotification"></span></i></div>
</div>

<div id="notepad" class="menu"></div>
<div id="news" class="menu"></div>
<div id="todo" class="menu"></div>
```

//JS

```
$('button').click(function(){    
    $('#todoListIcon').hide();
    resetPosition();
});


function resetPosition() {
    $('.icon').each(function(i){
        var obj = $(this);
        var left = obj.offset().left;
        var width = obj.width();
        var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
        var right = bodyWidth - (left + width);
        $('.menu').eq(i).css({'right':right+'px'});
    });
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yj25p1m1/3/)